# Can I use an variable in the [Route("x/{id}") of ASP.net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm making an Customers dashboard. In this dashboard each customer has one or more contacts. Those contacts have there own screen. To get acces to that screen I thought I would Implement a route with in it the ID of the selected Customer. Now I have to manually insert the Customersid. I would like that to be automatic. How do I do that?

My Code:

The Customer

```
public CustomerController()
        {
            _customers = new List<Models.Customer>();
            _customers.Add(new Models.Customer { Id = 1, Email = "Test1@gmail.com", Name = "Test1", Password = "Test1"});
            _customers.Add(new Models.Customer { Id = 2, Email = "Test12@gmail.com", Name = "Test12", Password = "Test12" });
            _customers.Add(new Models.Customer { Id = 3, Email = "Test123@gmail.com", Name = "Test123", Password = "Test123" });
            _customers.Add(new Models.Customer { Id = 4, Email = "Test1234@gmail.com", Name = "Test1234", Password = "Test1234" });
            _customers.Add(new Models.Customer { Id = 5, Email = "Test12345@gmail.com", Name = "Test12345", Password = "Test12345" });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetCustomers()
        {
            return Ok(_customers);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            foreach(var item in _customers)
            {
                if(id == item.Id)
                {
                    return Ok(item);
                }
            }
            return NoContent();
        }
```

The Contact:

```
 [Authorize]
    [Route("customer/{customerid}/contact")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ContactController : ControllerBase
    {
        private List<Models.Contact> _contacts;

        public ContactController()
        {
            _contacts = new List<Models.Contact>();
            _contacts.Add(new Models.Contact { Id = 1, Email = "Test1@gmail.com", Name = "Test1", Password = "Test1", Phone = 11111 });
            _contacts.Add(new Models.Contact { Id = 2, Email = "Test12@gmail.com", Name = "Test12", Password = "Test12", Phone = 1111 });
            _contacts.Add(new Models.Contact { Id = 3, Email = "Test123@gmail.com", Name = "Test123", Password = "Test123", Phone = 111 });
            _contacts.Add(new Models.Contact { Id = 4, Email = "Test1234@gmail.com", Name = "Test1234", Password = "Test1234", Phone = 11 });
            _contacts.Add(new Models.Contact { Id = 5, Email = "Test12345@gmail.com", Name = "Test12345", Password = "Test12345", Phone = 1 });

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetCustomers()
        {
            return Ok(_contacts);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetContact(int id)
        {
            foreach (var item in _contacts)
            {
                if (id == item.Id)
                {
                    return Ok(item);
                }
            }
            return NoContent();
        }
```

Comment: Your `Contact` model seems to be missing the `customerId`.

Comment: @tymtam You are right. But the project isn't finished yet. But I don't think it's nessesary for my problem at hand. If you have a solution that requires `Contact` to have a `customerId` I'll implement that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `ContactController` you can move the route data into the action instead and keep your route simple.

For example:

```
[Route("contact")]
[ApiController]
public class ContactController : ControllerBase

    [HttpGet("{customerId}/{contractId}")]
    public IActionResult GetContact(int customerId, int contactId)
    {

    }
```

You can then access this via `contact/1/1` which would give you the customer ID == 1 and contact ID == 1